# Use Python `set` keyword in Jinja

Tags: python, jinja2

I want to return unique items in Jinja template. Simplified:

```
{% set lst = [1, 2, 3, 3, 2] %}
{% for t in set(lst) %}
    {{ t }}
{% endfor %}
```

But this throws error:

```
UndefinedError: 'set' is undefined
```

And it seems hard to find answer on Google as `set` is also Jinja keyword.
So can I use Python's `set` keyword in Jinja, or can I return unique items from list in Jinja?

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Personally Python 3, but for this specific question I work in Python 2.7

Comment: Where is that error coming, on the first line or the second?

Comment: Error is coming from `{% for t in set(lst) %}`

Comment: Oh, misread your question. Deleted my answer.

Comment: check the edit on my answer. If you're using flask, it should work

Comment: LoL, so what's the answer?  It looks like a bug in Jinja.

Comment: Is there any way to create a set (hash set) in jinja2 in 2022. I am using salt and want to create a set for checking many times if an item is in it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using **jinja at least `v. 2.10`**:
you can use built-in filter `unique`:

```
{% set lst = [1, 2, 3, 3, 2] %}
{% for t in lst|unique %}
    {{ t }}
{% endfor %}
```

if your **jinja version is < 2.10** you can define this filter by yourself:

```
@app.template_filter('unique')
def unique(s):
    return list(set(s))
```

you can find more information about writing custom jinja filters [here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/#writing-filters)

Answer (score 0):

What set does is create a variable, so when you are using `set lst = 1`, you then access it with `lst`, not `set(lst)`

edit: misunderstood question, to access a python function from jinja, here's what I do in my flask app

```
@app.context_processor
def inject_python():
    return dict(set=set)
```

This way, jinja will have the function and you can use it as you did

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question, as OP intends to get a unique list, i.e. a set. Not the `jinja` specific keyword, but the vanilla Python function.